# Single click on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most people know how to bind "click' event to dynamically added element with

```
 $('#main').on('click','.link',function(){ //some code here });
```

Where `.link` is a dynamically added element. But how the code above should look like when i want to fire function only on first click? Yes, i know about `.one()`, but the question is to merge `.one()` with `.on()`.

Comment: `$('#main').one('click','.link',function(){ //some code here });` From jQuery 1.7, `one` accepts selector param to delegate event, just as `.on()`. Now it is depending result you are expecting, once for all links or once for each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery docs for show .one() and .on() are the same as of 1.7:

```
.one( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
 .on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to fire on the first click, you can unbind the listener after the execution.

```
$('#main').on('click', '.link', function() {
    $('#main').off('click', '.link');

    // do whatever you need here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> **Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

```
$('#main').one('click','.link',function(){
  //some code here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible straight-away to create delegated `on()` which will be fired at most once( i.e `one()`) because of the way delegated handler is wired up.

> **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):** When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

Thus the event will always be fired on descendent, even you detach the handler for the current element `.link` using `.off()` method inside the handler body.
However you can still achieve this by maintaining a list of DOM elements as a closure and match the list before doing actual code work.

```
var elements = [];//list of elements which is responded to events at once
$('#main').on('click', '.link', function() {
    if(matched){//match $(this)/ uniqueIdentifier in 'elements' array
      // prevent default and stopPropagation
      return;
    }
    elements.push($(this));//or push something like 'id' to uniquely identify current element
    //..codes
});
```